# Android record exists() in database?

Tags: java, android

I am looking to the fastest and the correct way to check if a record exists in the database:

```
public boolean Exists(String _id) {
    Cursor c=db.query(TABLENAME(), new String[] {"1"}, "_ID="+_id, null, null, null, null);
    if (!c.equals(null))
        return c.moveToFirst();
    return false;
}
```

Do you see any problem with it?

Comment: Checkout my answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27597922/android-sqlite-check-if-row-exists-in-table/43849296#43849296

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Consider that `mDb` is your `SqlLiteDatabase` class

```
public boolean Exists(String _id) {
   Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery("select 1 from yourTable where _id=%s", 
        new String[] { _id });
   boolean exists = (cursor.getCount() > 0);
   cursor.close();
   return exists;
}
```

- I keep your parameter `_id` as a `String` but I think it should be a `Long`.
- `select 1` is more fast than `select columnName` because the process doesn't need to retrieve all values from the table in the select clause.
- you can put the string `select 1 from...` in a static final constant to be even faster.

Comment: you should also close the cursor before returning a value. it doesn't cause a crash but it does give warnings.

Comment: Such a valuable answer! I never consider about a good way to check exits record till my current app, which works a lot with database. Really thank u!

Comment: @tbruyelle: I have to check a record is existed or not in listview, then present its. I implemented in getItemViewType in adapter, but it make app freeze until i touch anywhere, then it's just worked again :(
Is there a way to run it in another thread at getItemViewType?

Comment: @SteveLuck I can't say, you should post a question with all the details.

Comment: @tbruyelle: I posted a new thread here. Please have a look 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33427726/how-to-check-a-record-is-existed-in-database-inside-getitemviewtype

Comment: Why %s instead of "?'

Answer (score 6):

Since you are looking for an answer from 'credible and/or official sources', here in [`DatabaseUtils`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html) we have a method called `queryNumEntries`.

So your method could be made like this:

```
public boolean Exists(String _id) {
    return DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, TABLENAME(), "_ID=?", new String[] {"1"}) > 0;
}
```

Or, for faster one:

```
public boolean Exists(String _id) {
    return DatabaseUtils.longForQuery(db, "select count(*) from " + TABLENAME() + " where _ID=? limit 1", new String[] {"1"}) > 0;
}
```

Comment: This was the kind of answer I was looking for when I made the bounty. I wasn't aware of these DatabaseUtils before. If you wouldn't mind, could you briefly explain why longForQuery is faster? The documentation is a little sparse on that one.

Comment: I guess it is faster because of the LIMIT 1 clause,  preventing it from counting the number of rows if you have multiple rows that fulfills the selection criteria. However, since your criteria is _ID,  which can be assumed unique for a particular table, then both of them should be of the same speed.

Answer (score 5):

This question and the selected answer were helpful to me for understanding how to simply and quickly check if a record exits. However, I've seen many places that recommend against using `rawQuery` because of the possibility of SQL injection. (For example, [rawQuery Vs. database.query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8435932/rawquery-vs-database-query))

So here is what I decided on:

```
public boolean Exists(String searchItem) {

    String[] columns = { COLUMN_NAME };
    String selection = COLUMN_NAME + " =?";
    String[] selectionArgs = { searchItem };
    String limit = "1";

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, columns, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null, limit);
    boolean exists = (cursor.getCount() > 0);
    cursor.close();
    return exists;
}
```

I don't know if this is as fast as the selected answer or not, but after researching this it seems to conform to recommended Android conventions more.

**Update**

I now recommend @yuku's answer, but I won't delete mine yet because I still want to guide people away from using raw queries.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

In your DatabaseHelper, put this method...

```
public String Exist(String user) {        
     String username="";
     SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();               

     try { 
         Cursor c = db.query(TABLE_USER, null, KEY_USER + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(user)},null, null, null);                                               

         if (c == null) {                        
             return username;                                   
         }
         else {    
             c.moveToFirst();               
             username = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_USER)); 
         }                           
     }

     catch(Exception e){
         e.printStackTrace();
     }

     return username; 
}
```

then in your onClickListener, try to call the method that you create in your DatabaseHelper. Try this code:

```
String myUser = txtUser.getText().toString();
String storedUser = db.Exist(myUser);


//If Username exist
if (myUser.equals(storedUser)){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Username already exist!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout my answer here:
[Android Sqlite: Check if row exists in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27597922/android-sqlite-check-if-row-exists-in-table/43849296#43849296)

Answer (score 0):

This works good:

```
  Cursor cursor = null;
  String sql ="SELECT * FROM "+TableName+" WHERE ID="+idValue; 
  cursor= db.rawQuery(sql,null);
  Log.d("ISEXISTS","Cursor Count : " + cursor.getCount());

  boolean exists = (cursor.getCount() > 0);
  cursor.close();
```