# What must I do to implement SQLite's rawQuery() method?

Tags: android, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I'm trying to use the SQLite rawQuery method, based on the code here:

[Android record exists() in database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379550/android-record-exists-in-database)

...but I get "*The method rawQuery(String, String[]) is undefined for the type OdaaDBOpenHelper 
Authorize_Activity_DynamicControls.java*" with this code:

```
    OdaaDBOH = new OdaaDBOpenHelper(this);
. . .
    private boolean RecordExists(String _id) {
        // This:
        Cursor cursor = OdaaDBOH.rawQuery("select 1 from NAPOLEON_DYNAMITE_TABLE where _id=%s",  
        // or this:
        //Cursor cursor = OdaaDOdaaDBOpenHelperBOH.rawQuery("select 1 from     
NAPOLEON_DYNAMITE_TABLE where _id=%s",  
                new String[] { _id });
        boolean exists = (cursor.getCount() > 0); 
        cursor.close(); 
        return exists; 
    }

. . .
// from referenced unit:

public class OdaaDBOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
```

I tried it both using the instance name of my SQLiteOpenHelper-derived class, and using the class 
name itself (commented out in the code above).

What must I do to implement rawQuery() or cause it to be recognized/acknowledged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From that question correct answer:

*Consider that mDb is your SqlLiteDatabase class...*

**OdaaDBOH** should be an instance of a `SQLiteDatabase` if you want to use `rawQuery` on it, most likely you are providing the implementation of a `SQLiteOpenHelper` there, which of course doesn't have a method `rawQuery`.

Answer (score 3):

`rawQuery()` is a method on `SQLiteDatabase`, not `SQLiteOpenHelper`. Call `getReadableDatabase()` or `getWritableDatabase()` on your `SQLiteOpenHelper` to get a `SQLiteDatabase`.