# Android sqlite how to check if a record exists

Tags: android, sqlite

I would like to check whether a record exists or not.

Here is what I've tried:

**MainActivity.class**

```
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        System.out.println("Ontext changed " + new String(s.toString()));
        strDocumentFrom = s.toString();         

        if(s.toString().isEmpty()){

        } else {

             try{
                 strTransactionDate = dbHelper.getTransactionDateByDocumentNumber(strDocumentFrom);
                 //strTotalAmount = dbHelper.getTotalAmountByDocumentNumber(strDocumentFrom);
                 //strVan = dbHelper.getVanByDocumentNumber(strDocumentFrom);


                 //etTransactionDate.setText(strTransactionDate);
                 //etTotalAmount.setText(strTotalAmount);
                 //Log.d("Van", "" + strVan);
                 //etVan.setText(strVan);

             } catch (SQLiteException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
                 Toast.makeText(ReceivingStocksHeader.this, 
                         "Document number does not exist.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }

        }
```

**DBHelper.class**

```
            // TODO DISPLAYING RECORDS TO TRANSRCVHEADER
        public String getTransactionDateByDocumentNumber(String strDocumentNumber){
            String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_TRANSACTIONDATE};

            Cursor c = myDataBase.query(TBL_INTRANS, 
                    columns, null, 
                    null, null, null, null, null);

            if(c != null){
                c.moveToFirst();
                String date = c.getString(0);
                return date;
            } else {
                Log.d("Error", "No record exists");
            }


            return null;
        }
```

But it doesn't get it to the catch block to display the toast.

What am I doing wrong in here?

Answer (score 107):

```
public static boolean CheckIsDataAlreadyInDBorNot(String TableName,
        String dbfield, String fieldValue) {
    SQLiteDatabase sqldb = EGLifeStyleApplication.sqLiteDatabase;
    String Query = "Select * from " + TableName + " where " + dbfield + " = " + fieldValue;
    Cursor cursor = sqldb.rawQuery(Query, null);
        if(cursor.getCount() <= 0){
            cursor.close();
            return false;
        }
    cursor.close();
    return true;
}
```

I hope this is useful to you...
This function returns true if record already exists in db. Otherwise returns false.

Comment: Just added `cursor.close()` before returning. Ow it will give DatabaseLeak error

Comment: I would have added "LIMIT 1" to the query because you only want 1 row

Comment: While testing on Android 6.0.1, above query gave me SQLiteException.
It worked for me when I added fieldValue in double quotes (").

String Query = "Select * from " + TableName + " where " + dbfield + " = \"" + fieldValue + "\";";

Comment: @KapilJituri but this function is work for me for any android version.i have checked it.

Comment: @dipali Ok. Just a heads up, raw queries are more vulnerable to SQL Injection. Check my answer for preferred way.

Comment: what does the ` EGLifeStyleApplication` mean?

Comment: @SonnyP. its application class object.

Answer (score 34):

These are all good answers, however many forget to ***close the cursor and database***. If you don't close the cursor or database you may run in to memory leaks.

**Additionally:** 
You can get an error when searching by `String` that contains non alpha/numeric characters. For example: "`1a5f9ea3-ec4b-406b-a567-e6927640db40`". Those dashes (`-`) will cause an `unrecognized token` error. You can overcome this by putting the string in an array. So make it a habit to query like this:

```
public boolean hasObject(String id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    String selectString = "SELECT * FROM " + _TABLE + " WHERE " + _ID + " =?";

    // Add the String you are searching by here. 
    // Put it in an array to avoid an unrecognized token error 
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectString, new String[] {id}); 

    boolean hasObject = false;
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        hasObject = true;

        //region if you had multiple records to check for, use this region. 

        int count = 0;
        while(cursor.moveToNext()){
          count++;
        }
        //here, count is records found
        Log.d(TAG, String.format("%d records found", count));

        //endregion

    } 

    cursor.close();          // Dont forget to close your cursor
    db.close();              //AND your Database!
    return hasObject;
}
```

Comment: I prefer this answe because it takes into consideration the fact that strings may contain special characters like _ or-or :.Correct answer!!

Comment: Its true I was getting data from firebase, which had - and was gettting a wierd "no such column" issue even though the column was there....

Answer (score 14):

Raw queries are more vulnerable to SQL Injection. I will suggest using `query()` method instead.

```
public boolean Exists(String searchItem) {

    String[] columns = { COLUMN_NAME };
    String selection = COLUMN_NAME + " =?";
    String[] selectionArgs = { searchItem };
    String limit = "1";

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, columns, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null, limit);
    boolean exists = (cursor.getCount() > 0);
    cursor.close();
    return exists;
}
```

Source: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25256036/1270671)

Comment: Was unaware of `sqlinjection` with `rawQuery`.. Thanks for the info.. :)

Answer (score 11):

**SELECT EXISTS** with **LIMIT 1** is much faster.

*Query Ex*: `SELECT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column='value' LIMIT 1);`

*Code Ex:*

```
public boolean columnExists(String value) {
    String sql = "SELECT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column='"+value+"' LIMIT 1)";
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(sql, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    // cursor.getInt(0) is 1 if column with value exists
    if (cursor.getInt(0) == 1) { 
        cursor.close();
        return true;
    } else {
        cursor.close();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this solution is really cool, especially with LIMIT 1. But what about if i made it -  "SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ..... " Do you think that might be even faster?

Comment: @YoApps Not much if you ask me. See this answer https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/159413/exists-select-1-vs-exists-select-one-or-the-other

Answer (score 9):

You can use `SELECT EXISTS` command and execute it for a `cursor` using a `rawQuery`, 
from the documentation

> The EXISTS operator always evaluates to one of the integer values 0
>   and 1. If executing the SELECT statement specified as the right-hand
>   operand of the EXISTS operator would return one or more rows, then the
>   EXISTS operator evaluates to 1. If executing the SELECT would return
>   no rows at all, then the EXISTS operator evaluates to 0.

Answer (score 4):

I have tried all methods mentioned in this page, but only below method worked well for me.

```
Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM user WHERE idno='"+txtID.getText()+"'", null);
if(c.moveToFirst())
{
 showMessage("Error", "Record exist");
}
else
{
 // Inserting record
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One thing the top voted answer did not mention was that you need single quotes, 'like this', around your search value if it is a text value like so:

```
public boolean checkIfMyTitleExists(String title) {
    String Query = "Select * from " + TABLE_NAME + " where " + COL1 + " = " + "'" + title + "'";
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(Query, null);
    if(cursor.getCount() <= 0){
        cursor.close();
        return false;
    }
    cursor.close();

    return true;
}
```

Otherwise, you will get a "SQL(query) error or missing database" error like I did without the single quotes around the *title* field.

If it is a numeric value, it does not need single quotes.

Refer to this [SQL post for more details](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp)

Answer (score 1):

```
SQLiteDatabase sqldb = MyProvider.db;
String Query = "Select * from " + TABLE_NAME ;
Cursor cursor = sqldb.rawQuery(Query, null);
cursor.moveToLast(); //if you not place this cursor.getCount() always give same integer (1) or current position of cursor.

if(cursor.getCount()<=0){
    Log.v("tag","if 1 "+cursor.getCount());
    return false;
}
Log.v("tag","2 else  "+cursor.getCount());

return true;
```

if you not use `cursor.moveToLast()`;

`cursor.getCount()` always give same integer (`1`) or current position of cursor.

Answer (score 1):

**Code :**

```
private String[] allPushColumns = { MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_PUSH_ID,
        MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_PUSH_TITLE, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_PUSH_CONTENT, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_PUSH_TIME,
        MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_PUSH_TYPE, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_PUSH_MSG_ID}; 

public boolean checkUniqueId(String msg_id){

    Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_PUSH,
            allPushColumns, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_PUSH_MSG_ID + "=?", new String [] { msg_id }, null, null, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_PUSH_ID +" DESC");

    if(cursor.getCount() <= 0){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple solution based on a combination of what dipali and Piyush Gupta posted:

```
  public boolean dbHasData(String searchTable, String searchColumn, String searchKey) {
    String query = "Select * from " + searchTable + " where " + searchColumn + " = ?";
    return getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(query, new String[]{searchKey}).moveToFirst();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

because of possible data leaks best solution via cursor:

```
 Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
          cursor =  .... some query (raw or not your choice)
          return cursor.moveToNext();
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
```

1) From API *KITKAT* u can use resources try()

```
try (cursor = ...some query)
```

2) if u query against VARCHAR TYPE use  **'...'** eg. COLUMN_NAME='string_to_search'

3) dont use moveToFirst() is used when you need to start iterating from beggining

4) avoid getCount() is expensive - it iterates over many records to count them. It doesn't return a stored variable. There may be some caching on a second call, but the first call doesn't know the answer until it is counted.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use cursor.isNull method.
Example:

```
song.isFavorite = cursor.isNull(cursor.getColumnIndex("favorite"));
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use like this:**

```
String Query = "Select * from " + TABLE_NAME + " where " + Cust_id + " = " + cust_no;

Cursor cursorr = db.rawQuery(Query, null);
if(cursor.getCount() <= 0){
cursorr.close();
}
cursor.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private boolean checkDataExistOrNot(String columnName, String value) {
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = getReadableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM" + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + columnName + " = " + value;
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(query, null);
    if (cursor.getCount() <= 0) {
        cursor.close();
        return false;  // return false if value not exists in database
    }
    cursor.close();
    return true;  // return true if value exists in database
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to do it this way because it's fast and less expensive than other methods:

```java
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE condition = 1 LIMIT 1", null);
try {
    if (cursor.moveToNext()) {
       //Record exists
    } else {
       //Record doesn't exists
    }
} finally {
    cursor.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My version:

```
public boolean isTitleExists(String title, String type) {
    int isExists = 0;
    try {
        String query = "SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM titles WHERE title = ? and type = ?)";

        PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        statement.setString(1, title);
        statement.setString(2, type);

        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
        rs.next();
        isExists = rs.getInt(1);
        rs.close();
        statement.close();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Common.console("isTitleExists error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return isExists == 1;
}
```