# Check if some string is in SQLite database

Tags: android, string, sqlite

I have some trouble with a SQLite database with 1 table and 2 columns, `column_id` and `word`. I extended `SQLiteAssetHelper` as `MyDatabase` and made a constructor:

```
public MyDatabase(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
```

I need to check whether some string is in the database (in column `word`). I tried to modify the code from [answer provided by  Benjamin and dipali](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20415309/android-sqlite-how-to-check-if-a-record-exists), but I used `SQLiteAssetHelper` and I can't get it to work. The method that I have in mind receives the string to search for as a parameter and returns a boolean if string is in the database.

```
public boolean someMethod(String s)
```

In addition, I tried to put the check on a background thread with `AsyncTask` because I have 60 strings to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TABLE_NAME` and `COLUMN_WORD` should be self-explanatory.

```
public boolean someMethod(String s) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    String[] columns = new String[] {COLUMN_WORD};
    String where = COLUMN_WORD + " = ?";
    String[] whereArgs = new String[] {s};

    // select column_word from table where column_word = 's' limit 1;
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, columns, where, whereArgs, null, null, null, "1");
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        return true; // a row was found
    }
    return false; // no row was found
}
```

You can do this in the background, but I don't think for a query like this it's even necessary.

**EDIT**

There are some improvements that should be made to the above for the sake of correctness. For one thing, the `Cursor` should be closed since it is no longer being used. A try-finally block will ensure this:

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(...);
try {
    return cursor.moveToFirst();
} finally {
    cursor.close();
}
```

However, this method doesn't need to obtain a whole `Cursor. You can write it as follows and it should be more performant:

```
public boolean someMethod(String s) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    String sql = "select count(*) from " + TABLE_NAME + " where "
            + COLUMN_WORD + " = " + DatabaseUtils.sqlEscapeString(s);
    SQLiteStatement statement = db.compileStatement(sql);

    try {
        return statement.simpleQueryForLong() > 0;
    } finally {
        statement.close();
    }
}
```

You could add a `catch` block and `return false` if you think it's possible (and valid) to encounter certain exceptions like `SQLiteDoneException`. Also note the use of [`DatabaseUtils.sqlEscapeString()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#sqlEscapeString(java.lang.String)) because `s` is now concatenated directly into the query string and thus we should be wary of SQL injection. (If you can guarantee that `s` is not malicious by the time it gets passed in as the method argument, then you could theoretically skip this, but I wouldn't.)

Comment: The single quotes for the question mark (?) in String Where is causing the ANR in my case.

Comment: Thanks @Ravi, I removed the single quotes and also added a new section with other improvements.

Answer (score 0):

because of possible data leaks best solution via cursor:

```
 Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
          cursor =  .... some query (raw or not your choice)
          return cursor.moveToNext();
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
```

1) From API *KITKAT* u can use resources try()

```
try (cursor = ...some query)
```

2) if u query against VARCHAR TYPE use  **'...'** eg. COLUMN_NAME='string_to_search'

3) dont use moveToFirst() is used when you need to start iterating from beggining

4) avoid getCount() is expensive - it iterates over many records to count them. It doesn't return a stored variable. There may be some caching on a second call, but the first call doesn't know the answer until it is counted.