# How to get error code of SQLiteConstraintException in Java

Tags: java, android, sqlite, exception

I'm trying to catch the following exception specifically for **code 19.** 
Is there any way of getting [the error code](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_abort.html) of SQLiteConstraintException ? or should I simply have a "contains" check for the message description ?

03-24 14:46:45.430: W/System.err(2219): android.database.sqlite.**SQLiteConstraintException**: PRIMARY KEY must be unique (code 19)

```
        try {
            res = database.insertOrThrow(EMP_TABLE, null, values);      
        } catch (android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
             //something like e.getErrorCode(); }
```

My workaround solution is ;

```
    if(e.getMessage().contains("code 19"))
      Log.d(TAG, "Key Already exists !");
```

Comment: Instead of catching exception, check does given row already exists. Then you do not have to handle exception.

Comment: how do I do that check ?  by another sql statement?

Comment: Why would you need that ? You can use  res = database.insert(EMP_TABLE, null, values);      and you won't get any exception. You just need to check the value of res. if it is -1 then there is some error else not.

Comment: I need to know if the key already exists or not so that I will prompt the user if he wants to update the row or not.

Comment: @shamaleyte Exactly, by another sql query. Please find more information about that in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20415309/android-sqlite-how-to-check-if-a-record-exists thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's not available as a method, you can't retrieve it directly, you have to search for it, or create your own Exception extending `SQLiteConstraintException` but you'd have to search for it anyway. If you are worried about performance, you could use `indexOf("code 19")` instead.

But depending on what you are trying to do, it's probably best in terms of code clarity and flow to actually check if the key exists before attempting to insert it and acting on the exception specifically for that.

Comment: For the sake of presenting alternates to the solution, I will accept your answer even though there is no way of getting the error code.  credit to @jakubbialkowski as well