# Implement two methods on one button

Tags: android, android-sqlite, buttonclick, android-imagebutton

I have two methods to add and remove data from a sqlite table. Both of these methods work fine separately. What i would like to do is implement both methods on one button.
On button click if the data exists in the table remove the data else add the data if it doesn't exist and change the drawable in the image button. I tried a lot of things but i can't figure out how to do that .

Here is my code

```
public boolean addBookmark(String id, String word, String definition) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COL_ID, id);
    values.put(COL_WORD, word);
    values.put(COL_DEFINITION, definition);
    db.insert(TABLE_BOOKMARK, null, values);

    return true;
}

public Integer deleteBookmark(String id){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    return db.delete(TABLE_BOOKMARK, "id = ?",new String[]{id});
}
```

i did something like this but it is not working i get error in logcat.

```
  public  boolean isBookmark(String id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String Query = "Select * from " + TABLE_BOOKMARK + " where " + id + " = ?" ;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(Query, null);
        if(cursor.getCount() <= 0){
            cursor.close();
            return false;
        }
        cursor.close();
        return true;
    }
```

and in onclick

```
  public void onClick(View v) {

            boolean isBookmark = mDBHelper.isBookmark(id);

            if (isBookmark){

                mDBHelper.deleteBookmark(id);
                btnBookmark.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_bookmark_border);
            } else {
                mDBHelper.addBookmark(id,word,definition);
                btnBookmark.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_bookmark_fill);
            }
```

here is my logcat error

```
2019-02-22 19:36:53.391 28210-28210/com.elytelabs.testnav E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting definition=Create a new folder by going to New > Directory . In the dialog box that opens name the directory fragment or any name of your choice.
Create a new Fragment file inside the created directory and name it dictionary or any word of your choice.
  id=7 word=rvvg
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: bookmark.id (code 1555 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_PRIMARYKEY)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:796)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1564)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1433)
    at com.elytelabs.testnav.database.DatabaseHelper.addBookmark(DatabaseHelper.java:125)
    at com.elytelabs.testnav.DetailActivity$1.onClick(DetailActivity.java:68)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
    at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: A simple logical statement in  your onclick method with the logic you define in your question should solve the problem. What is your code in onclick method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following line of code in `isBookmark` is incorrect:

```
String Query = "Select * from " + TABLE_BOOKMARK + " where " + id + " = ?" ;
```

I believe that will create a select statement that looks like the following:

```
"Select * from TABLE where 5 = ?"
```

*Of course I don't know what your TABLE_BOOKMARK const value actually is so I put the table name in as TABLE.  And, I arbitrarily used the id value of 5.

The statement should be formed something like the following:

```
String Query = "Select * from " + TABLE_BOOKMARK + " where id = " + id;
```

This seems to make sense too, because it means your isBookmark never deletes the record value that you expect it to delete (since it never successfully finds a record that matches the query).  That means the insert always fails because the record actually still exists.

Comment: thanks. Your solution works great but i can't set different drawables for the if else statement on click the drawable gets changed. But it doesn't stay that way

Answer (score 0):

You first need to check if the data exists, and then you can add or remove the data.

For example, use a method like this.

```
public static boolean CheckIsDataAlreadyInDBorNot(String TableName,
        String dbfield, String fieldValue) {
    SQLiteDatabase sqldb = EGLifeStyleApplication.sqLiteDatabase;
    String Query = "Select * from " + TableName + " where " + dbfield + " = " + fieldValue;
    Cursor cursor = sqldb.rawQuery(Query, null);
        if(cursor.getCount() <= 0){
            cursor.close();
            return false;
        }
    cursor.close();
    return true;
}
```

Taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/20416004/3106174

Then, you can simply do.

```
if( CheckIsDataAlreadyInDBorNot( ... ) ) {
    deleteBookmark( ... );
} else {
    addBookmark( ... );
}
```

Comment: Do i need to add id , word , definition or only id , and word will do

Comment: To check if the row exists, I think you'd only need to check for the `id`, since that should be unique.