# Problems with detection value in a db

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I'm trying to find value at db and for example show log. I used this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20416004/9363441) with my data:

```
public boolean CheckIsDataAlreadyInDBorNot_2(String fieldValue) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String Query = "Select * FROM " + Job.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + Job.COLUMN_JOB_DATE + " = " + fieldValue;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(Query, null);
    if (cursor.getCount() <= 0) {
        cursor.close();
        return false;
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return true;
}
```

I'm trying to check whether db contains some specific datafield. I call this method:

```
if (DataBaseHelper.getInstance(ctx).CheckIsDataAlreadyInDBorNot_2("28.02.2019")) {
    Log.i("m", "data at db");
} else {
    Log.i("m", "not in db");
}
```

The following line is at db, but I receive such mistake:

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ".2019": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: Select * FROM selected_jobs WHERE job_last_date = 28.02.2019

I can't understand how I can solve this problem.

Comment: Maybe use single quotations around your string: `CheckIsDataAlreadyInDBorNot_2("'28.02.2019'")` ?

Comment: @Burdui, thank you so much :)

Comment: @Burdui, maybe you can say how I can use single quotations around string from textView, for example smth like this - 'textView.getText()'?

Comment: `for example smth like this - 'textView.getText()'?`- something like `"'" + textView.getText() + "'"` will do. But please note that the date format you are using is WRONG (it won't be seen as a **date** by SQLite date functions). You should use the ISO format: `'2019-02-28'`.

Comment: @Fantômas, I'm getting this date after formatting date which I get from server, I can create a new question and maybe you will see my mistake, whether it is possible?

Comment: Hopefully, on the server, the date is stored in the **proper format**: `2019-02-28` then your query MUST read: `SELECT * FROM selected_jobs WHERE job_last_date = '2019-02-28'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with date as a string like '28.02.2019', and call the function like this:

```
CheckIsDataAlreadyInDBorNot_2("28.02.2019")
```

Or using textView

```
CheckIsDataAlreadyInDBorNot_2(textView.getText().toString())
```

So, the query will become:

```
String Query = "Select * FROM " + Job.TABLE_NAME
             + " WHERE " +
               Job.COLUMN_JOB_DATE + " = '" + fieldValue + "'";
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: in general I won't use this string, I'm getting data from textView , so if you know how use text from textView I will be so pleased to you :)

Comment: means you are sending the string in parameter using textView?