# How to loop through SQlL table t

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sqlite, android-studio

How do I look through my database and find out if the database already contain the data I am trying to parse into it

My Database:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE UserInfo(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Users_Name TEXT, PlaylistName TEXT,likeAlbum TEXT)");
    }
```

code:

```
public boolean check_If_Data_In_DataBase(String albumName) {
        boolean bool = false;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor  = db.rawQuery("SELECT likeAlbum FROM " + Table_Name,null);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            String name = cursor.getString(0);
            bool = name == albumName;
        }
        cursor.close();
        return bool;
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20415309/android-sqlite-how-to-check-if-a-record-exists

Answer (score 1):

```
Select count(*) as count from <table> where name = <albumname>
```

as return you get a table with only one row and column and this field displays how many rows in your table fulfill the creteria in the where clause,

so if it returns 0 the data is not in the table if it returns >=1 it is