# check if row already exist in sqlite database

Tags: android, listview, android-sqlite

```html
LogCat error:

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                      Process: com.sam.shoppingcart, PID: 31773
                                                                      android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "Beef": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT KEY_NAME FROM shop WHERE KEY_NAME=Corned Beef
                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:893)
                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:504)
                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1278)
                                                                          at com.sam.shoppingcart.SQLiteHandler.ifExists(SQLiteHandler.java:63)
                                                                          at com.sam.shoppingcart.CustomListAdapter$1.onClick(CustomListAdapter.java:77)
```

I've a listview using custom adapter with an "Add" and "Remove" button. When one clicks Add button, the Name and Price gets of the LV item gets added to DB. I want to check while adding if the LV item is already present in DB or not. For that I created ifExists(Model model) function in DBHandler. But now on clicking Add button it gives me error. What I'm doing wrong? PS: I got the function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27597922/android-sqlite-check-if-row-exists-in-table).

```js
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView listView;
    private ArrayList<Model> mListData;
    private CustomListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);


        mListData = new ArrayList<>();

        mListData.add(new Model("Beef Manhattan", "50"));
        mListData.add(new Model("Chicken Fried Steak", "90"));
        mListData.add(new Model("Corned Beef", "100"));
        mListData.add(new Model("Domesticated Turkey", "80"));
        mListData.add(new Model("Eggs Benedict", "10"));
        mListData.add(new Model("French Dip", "20"));
        mListData.add(new Model("Green Bean Casserole", "30"));
        mListData.add(new Model("Potato Salad", "40"));
        mListData.add(new Model("Pumpkin Pie", "60"));
        mListData.add(new Model("Salisbury Steak", "70"));

        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, R.layout.listrow, mListData);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);



    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action) {

            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, NextActivity.class));
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

```css
public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Model> {

    private Context mContext;
    int resource;
    private ArrayList<Model> mListData = new ArrayList<Model>();



    public CustomListAdapter(Context mContext, int resource, ArrayList<Model> mListData) {
        super(mContext, resource, mListData);
        this.resource = resource;
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mListData = mListData;
    }

    public void setListData(ArrayList<Model> mListData) {
        this.mListData = mListData;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return super.getCount();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (v == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();

                v = inflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);

                holder.name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
                holder.rate = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.rate);
                holder.add = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.add);
                holder.remove = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.remove);


            v.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }




        final Model item = mListData.get(position);

            holder.name.setText(item.getName());
            holder.rate.setText(item.getRate());
            holder.add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                   SQLiteHandler db = new SQLiteHandler(getContext());

                    if(db.ifExists(item)){


                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Already Present", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }else{
                        db.addItems(holder.name.getText().toString(), holder.rate.getText().toString());
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }


                }
            });

            holder.remove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    SQLiteHandler db = new SQLiteHandler(getContext());
                    db.deleteItem(item);
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Removed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });

        return v;
    }

    class ViewHolder {

        TextView name;
        TextView rate;
        Button add;
        Button remove;
    }

}
```

```html
public class SQLiteHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

 private static final String TAG = SQLiteHandler.class.getSimpleName();

 // All Static variables
 // Database Version
 private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

 // Database Name
 private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "android_api";

 // Profile Settings table name
 private static final String TABLE_SHOP = "shop";

 // Profile Settings information names
 private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
 private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
 private static final String KEY_PRICE = "price";


 public SQLiteHandler(Context context) {
  super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
 }

 // Creating Tables
 @Override
 public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

  String CREATE_PROF_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_SHOP + "("+KEY_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "+KEY_NAME+" TEXT,  "+KEY_PRICE+" TEXT" + ")";

  db.execSQL(CREATE_PROF_TABLE);

  Log.d(TAG, "Database tables created");
 }

 // Upgrading database
 @Override
 public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
  // Drop older table if existed
  db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_SHOP);

  // Create tables again
  onCreate(db);
 }

 // Check before adding item if item already exist
 SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
 public boolean ifExists(Model model) {
  Cursor cursor = null;
  String checkQuery = "SELECT KEY_NAME FROM "+TABLE_SHOP+" WHERE KEY_NAME="+model.getName();
  cursor= db.rawQuery(checkQuery,null);
  boolean exists = (cursor.getCount() > 0);
  cursor.close();
  return exists;
 }


    // Add items to db
 public void addItems(String name, String mobile){

  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

  ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

  values.put(KEY_NAME, name);
  values.put(KEY_PRICE, mobile);

  long id = db.insert(TABLE_SHOP, null, values); // insert to 1st row
  db.close(); // Closing database connection

  Log.d(TAG, "New products inserted into sqlite: " + id);

 }




 // Fetch all data
 public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getProfDetails()
    {
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> array_list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_SHOP;
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        res.moveToFirst();

        while (res.isAfterLast() == false)
        {
            HashMap<String, String> hashmap= new HashMap<String, String>();
            hashmap.put("name", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME)));
            hashmap.put("price", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(KEY_PRICE)));

            array_list.add(hashmap);
            res.moveToNext();
        }
        return array_list;
    }

 // Getting Sum of "price"
 public int sumofPrice(){
  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
  String selectQuery = "SELECT  SUM(price) FROM " + TABLE_SHOP;
  Cursor cur = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
  int total=0;
  if(cur.moveToFirst())
  {
   total = cur.getInt(0);
  }
  return total;
 }

 // Delete single row
 public void deleteItem(Model model) {
  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
  db.delete(TABLE_SHOP, KEY_NAME + " = ?",new String[] { String.valueOf(model.getName()) });
  db.close();
 }

 // Delete whole table
 public void deleteTable() {
  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
  // Delete All Rows
  db.delete(TABLE_SHOP, null, null);
  db.close();

  Log.d(TAG, "Deleted all info from sqlite");
 }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check below your updated method for ifExists(),

```
     public boolean ifExists(Model model)
     {
         Cursor cursor = null;
         String checkQuery = "SELECT " + KEY_NAME + " FROM " + TABLE_SHOP + " WHERE " + KEY_NAME + "= '"+model.getName() + "'";
          cursor= db.rawQuery(checkQuery,null);
          boolean exists = (cursor.getCount() > 0);
          cursor.close();
          return exists;
     }
```

Two things, first is you were passing variable as value for column name and second thing is you were passing name value with space and without quote them so it will crash app.

Now try above code.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much, @Vicky

Comment: Can you also help me with another query? @Vicky

Comment: I'm fetching my items from DB in another activity's listview. I'm able to delete single row using function deleteItem(Model model). But the listview doesn't empties event when I have deleted everything from listview. It still shows the last one. And when I press back button and then again come back to this activity now it shows empty. Why?

Comment: for that you need to show me your code related to this, and first thing you can do is just check the condition for setting adapter, as sometimes we set condition as if list.size() > 0, then only assign list to adapter and therefore if there is no data then it will not notify change and show last record as it is in list, so check that and then also if any query then show me code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114015/discussion-between-somnath-pal-and-vickyexpert).

Answer (score 1):

in your ifExists function

```
String checkQuery = "SELECT KEY_NAME FROM "+TABLE_SHOP+" WHERE KEY_NAME="+model.getName();
```

change it to

```
 String checkQuery = "SELECT "+KEY_NAME+" FROM "+TABLE_SHOP+" WHERE "+KEY_NAME+"="+model.getName();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private boolean hasRow(String id) {
        String selectString = "SELECT * FROM " + tablename + " WHERE " +
                id + " =?";
        sqliteDatabase = getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = sqliteDatabase.rawQuery(selectString, new String[] {id});

        boolean hasObject = false;
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            hasObject = true;
        }

        cursor.close();
        sqliteDatabase.close(); //Close the database
        return hasObject; //return value.
    }
```

This will find the first occurrence and will say yes this row is present.
To get how many rows are present use

```
while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
count++;
}
```