# How to check a record is existed in database inside getItemViewType

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I have a list of products, each row has a function "Save" which will store the item product to local database. I'm using SwipeMenuListView via https://github.com/baoyongzhang/SwipeMenuListView and i have to check record is existed or not in getItemViewType in ListAdapter to remove function Save of the row which saved.
But the problem is, the "check record is existed or not" made my listview freeze after notifyDataSetChanged for a while (click "Save" then notifyDataSetChanged then list is freezed until i touch listview again).
How should i fix it? 
Every suggestion will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance. Here is my code:

```
@Override
public boolean onMenuItemClick(int position, SwipeMenu menu, int index) {
   switch (index) {
   case 0:
      break;
   case 1:
   ProductDetailsVo.ProductInfo productInfo = listResult.get(position);
   insertProductToDB(productInfo);
   break;
}
```

and method insertProductToDB:

```
private void insertProductToDB(ProductDetailsVo.ProductInfo productInfo) {
   databaseManager.insertProductToDB(productInfo);
   if (adapter != null) {
   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
}
```

Adapter:

```
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
   return 2;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
   if (databaseManager.isProductSaved(listProds.get(position).getProductId())) {// cause listview freeze
      return 1;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So the freezes are probably due the numerous calls to `isProductSaved`, you can be sure of that by commenting them and test, or by profiling your app with the Android Device Monitor.

You can easily remove that database access by adding a field `exists` to your products. The default value would be `false` and `insertProductToDB` would set it to true if the insertion succeeds. With that your `getViewType` will be much faster.

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
   if (listProds.get(position).isExists())) {
      return 1;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

If you don't want to alter your model object with an extra field, you can also maintain a map like a `SparseArray` in the adapter. It would contain the `id` of the saved products.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that databaseManager.isProductSaved was run on UI thread. I thought about a field "isExist" in object, but if user back to previous screen then coming in, the obj will be created new after loading from server.

Comment: Populate the field `exists` just after you fetch the items, and before the list is displayed.

Comment: How can i check a product item which fetched from server is saved in local db? Maybe i need an array to store saved ids?